# Automapper: second mapping throws missing typemap

Tags: c#, automapper

after initializing Automapper and calling `Mapper.Map` typeMap is null and second call to `Mapper.Map` throws exception "Missing type map".

I have initialized the Mapping:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
                { 
                    cfg.CreateMap<Role, AppRole>();
                });
                Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Then after calling :

```
var roleTest = Mapper.Map<Role, AppRole>(role);
var mapped = Mapper.Configuration.FindTypeMapFor(typeof(Role), typeof(AppRole)); // here mapped is null
var roleTestSecond = Mapper.Map<Role, AppRole>(role); // exception thrown "Missing type map"
```

Do you have any idea why the second mapping is not working and the typemap is missing? Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this your actual code? What you have posted here will not throw that exception.

Comment: It throws. Its my actual code. I am asking because I know it is not supposed to throws exception

Comment: Doesn't throw when I try it here...

Comment: So maybe it is something in other parts of the code. I will keep searching

Comment: Do these classes contain nested complex types? For what type do you get this missing type map exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with static Mapper. My solution is to make static class like ConveriosnExtensions. See below:

```
      public static class DataConversionsExtensions
    {
        private static readonly IMapper Mapper;

        static DataConversionsExtensions()
        {
            var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Field, DbField>();
                cfg.CreateMap<DbField, Field>();  });

            Mapper = new Mapper(configuration);
        }

        public static Field ToField(this DbField field)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<Field>(field);
        }

        public static DbField ToDbField(this Field field)
        {
            return Mapper.Map<DbField>(field);
        }
}
```

That way you are sure which configuration you are currently using and you can use conversion very easily:

```
var field = dbfield.ToField();
```

This also nicely encapsulates the whole process, so no more copy-pasting of code

EDIT: Of course, years later I would not use static class, but a DI container and just inject the IMapper when I need it

Comment: I will try this

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you need to seal your configuration for the FindTypeMapFor to return anything.

Try adding a call to seal to your auto mapper initialize.

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            { 
                cfg.CreateMap<Role, AppRole>();
            });
            Mapper.Configuration.Seal();
            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Comment: Not as far as I can tell. Seal makes no difference.

Comment: I suggested this after seeing this comment in an automapper unit test:
// If sealed _typeMapCache is filled and should be able to Resolve tye TypeMap
// If not sealed _typeMapCache is empty and should return null
I may very well of taken this comment out of its context. Shall see if it helps the OP.

Comment: Even if this did matter, that's only going to make the `FindTypeMapFor` method return null. The problem is the next line that throws the exception.